# Can I iterate through a whole CSV checking only one column

Tags: python, pandas

I know the main question is simple sounding, but I am specifically trying to iterate a whole CSV to find a certain variable while maintaining all the other columns connected to it. I am trying to create a file that essentially checks a certain date and then emails reminders or other templates to a list of students that qualify (based on the date or course) for the reminders. Currently with my code, I can't figure a way to keep the variables linked. I can get a list of students that I want to email, but am having trouble with the names staying linked to the emails I want.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta
import os
from email.message import EmailMessage

df = pd.read_excel('Students.xlsx')

EMAIL_ADDRESS = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
MAIL_LIST = ''
STUDENT_MAIL = df.student_email
DUE_DATE = df.course_completion_date
COURSE = df.course_section
START_DATE = dt.date.today()
END_DATE = START_DATE + timedelta(days=6)
```

I then have my codes for basic templates which I have tested and used prior so I know work.
But then I have tried several loops to try and add student emails to it through a loop so for example I would want all students finishing within a week to receive an email

```
for date in DUE_DATE:
    if START_DATE <= date <= END_DATE:
        MAIL_LIST = MAIL_LIST + STUDENT_EMAIL
    else:
```

Now I know this looks dumb but this was just my last attempt at trying to get it to work. But I have tried several other ways to get it to work but the problem I run into is that the for loop has to be a single column to make a list it can check against but I need it connected to the second column of their emails to make the mailing list. Am I overcomplicating this I feel like I'm kind of going crazy

Answer (score 0):

Using the DataFrame already will keep the variables linked like you would for index in rows and columns.

If you are trying to just grab the row matching the email you can use `.loc` to find the matching row for students to emails.

something like:

```
df.loc[x]['MAIL_LIST']
```

[pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)